# How to obtain tilde or approx symbol in gnuplot legend?

Tags: gnuplot, legend, approximation, tilde

I want to use either tilde (~) or approximate symbol (in latex \approx) in the legend of my gnuplot.

I am using **epscairo** terminal.

I tried seting either:
*set encoding iso_8859_1*

or

*set encoding utf8*

and using different commands, for example **\176** as descbribed here (http://ayapin-film.sakura.ne.jp/Gnuplot/Docs/ps_guide.pdf), but nothing seems to work.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: If you use utf8 encoding, you can copy any symbol into your script (if the font you use supports it, of course).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems `'\~'` or `"\\~"` works for me for tilde. `"{/Symbol \273}"` produces ≈.

Comment: Thank you! I did not use both /Symbol and \273 at the same time!